# How can I make a global variable in axios?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, axios, global-variables

So, I am just learning about axios and everything looks right, but I suppose I'm not understanding something about global scopes. Here is my code:

```
axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/social-collab')
.then(function (response) {
console.log('Response: ', response.data);
const data = response.data;
return data;
})
.catch(function (handleError) {
console.log('Error: ', handleError);
},[]);

const myData = function(data) {

name = data.name; // This is the line with the error: data is not defined. But it is, isn't it?
return name;
}

console.log(myData(data));
```

Comment: Here, in your code you've defined `const data` in your `axios` API response, so the scope will be block level i.e., it'll be accessible only inside `then()`. That's why you are getting error. What exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Axios confuses me because the whole axios isn't enclosed in braces: `axios.get() { /* .then and .catch */ }` so it makes me ask, how does it know the variable data would be associated to axios? It just looks different from all the other JavaScript I've learned in the past 5 weeks at school.

Comment: Ok, I tried that and got what I thought would happen. Now, `const data = response.data` has "response is not defined" and that's because it's **not** within the `.then`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a global scope, just chain another `.then` with your function `myData`.

```js
const myData = function(data) {
  name = data.name;
  console.log('name:', name)
  return name;
}

axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/social-collab')
.then(response => {
  const data = response.data;
  return data
})
.then(myData)
.catch(err => {
  console.log('Error: ', err);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

The way to get data out of Promises is by supplying a function to `.then`.

Answer (score 0):

If you return something from an `async` function (`promise` which will get your data from somewhere else) then you won't get the return value immediately. You can check my solution to understand better.

```js
function getData() {
  axios
    .get("https://api.github.com/users/social-collab")
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log("Response: ", response.data);
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (handleError) {
      console.log("Error: ", handleError);
    }, []);
}

const myData = function (data) {
  name = data.name;
  console.log(name);
};

getData().then((data) => {
  myData(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
```